# How to post date data from widget date package flutter to database?

Tags: laravel, flutter

I use this flutter package to select date data in flutter. The package is flutter_datetime_picker: 1.2.5. I dont know how to post date data to the database. I want as user select the date data. The date data should be updated in the database.

Below is the code for select date.

**date.dart**

```
RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                elevation: 4.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                      theme: DatePickerTheme(
                        containerHeight: 210.0,
                      ),
                      showTitleActions: true,
                      minTime: DateTime(2019, 1, 1),
                      maxTime: DateTime(2030, 12, 31), onConfirm: (date) {
                    print('confirm $date');
                    returnDate = '${date.year} - ${date.month} - ${date.day}';
                    setState(() {

                    });

                  }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
                },
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.date_range,
                                  size: 25.0,
                                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                ),
                                new Text(
                                  " $returnDate",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 18.0),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "  Change",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
              ),
```

I have done the API in laravel and run in postman and data were able to be post. I dont know how to post date data in flutter to the database.
This is my API function.

**.api**

```
 public function PostTrip(Request $request)
         {
            $id = $request->id; 
            $traveller_id = $request->taveller_id;
            $departDate = $request->departDate;
            $returnDate = $request->returnDate;

            $getId = User::where('id',$id)->first()->id;
            //// called country based on id ////

             $user = PosTrip::create([

                'traveller_id'=>$getId,
                'departDate'=>$departDate,
                'returnDate'=>$returnDate,

            ]);


                $datamsg = response()->json([
                'success' => array("text"=>"Done!")
                ]);
                return $datamsg->content();



         }
```

Need few inputs, After selecting date, if I want to save the date in database ,what need to be done?

Comment: try using Carbon to parse those dates from Flutter

Comment: i have never used carbon before. Is it in the laravel api or in flutter? Where can I get the reference?

Comment: It is in Laravel so you will parse the date as ```$departDate = Carbon::parse($request->departDate);``` dont forget to import Carbon

Comment: what do you mean by import the Carbon?

Comment: i mean ```use Carbon\Carbon``` its built in Laravel